# Customize Global Exception Handler in java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception

My GlobalExceptionHandler

```
@ControllerAdvice("uz.pdp.warehouse")
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({RuntimeException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<DataDto<AppError>> handle500(RuntimeException e, WebRequest webRequest) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                new DataDto<>(AppErrorDto.builder()
                        .message(e.getMessage())
                        .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                        .path(webRequest.getContextPath())
                        .build()));
    }

}
```

I want to return my customized ResponseEntity but it returns something different

```
{
"timestamp": "2022-03-27T06:21:00.845+00:00",`
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"trace": "uz.pdp.warehouse.exception.NotFoundException: QWE\r\n",
"message": "QWE",
"path": "/test/testN"
}
```

then I also catch exception with `try{}catch(){}` it is working but I want to handle exception via my `GlobalExceptionHandler`.

```
so what can I do?
```

is it possible return customized `AppError` or `ResposeEntity`?

Comment: does `uz.pdp.warehouse.exception.NotFoundException` extend `RuntimeException` or just `Exception`?

Comment: You first refer to this https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-controlleradvice-exceptionhandler/ tutorial, try again your self and come back if it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to extend ResponseEntityExceptionHandler as follows:

```
@ControllerAdvice("uz.pdp.warehouse")
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler  {

    @ExceptionHandler({RuntimeException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<DataDto<AppError>> handle500(RuntimeException e, WebRequest webRequest) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                new DataDto<>(AppErrorDto.builder()
                        .message(e.getMessage())
                        .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                        .path(webRequest.getContextPath())
                        .build()));
    }

}
```

Comment: add code blocks properly